# Signed Java Applet not Working

Tags: java, applet, certificate, code-signing

I'm working on a Java Applet that used to be self-signed.  Now that java 7u51 is being used, I am working to get the jar for the Applet signed.

I used the certificate/key used for the apache2 ssl to sign the jar.  In order to do this I had to create a new keystore using the key/certificate, and the [Not Yet Commons SSL](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/) library.

If I run jarsigner -verify on the applet jar, i get:

```
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate's ExtendedKeyUsage extension
doesn't allow code signing.
```

The applet is still getting an invalid certificate error.  I can view the certificate, and it is the same certificate used for SSL.  The error message says that it was blocked due to being self-signed, but this is not a self-signed certificate!

I can run the applet when I move the security settings down to "medium", but this is unacceptable for this project.

The certificate I used to sign this is part of a chain (about 4 long).  Is there a way I need sign the jar using the whole chain? Do I need to use a Code Signing certificate?

Comment: You may or may not be interested in setting up a new build tool to solve your problem so I'm just leaving it as a comment, but you should check out Gradle - it's a very powerful yet very easy to use build tool which includes, among many other features, a jar-signing plugin which can be invoked as part of your build.  All you would need is a private/public key pair, and they give you instructions on setting it up.  http://www.gradle.org/

Comment: I'm currently using Ant for this (old) project, which just calls jarsign.  I've been using Maven for new projects, but will check out Gradle.

Comment: I think you'll like Gradle more than Maven.  Gradle has the same support that Maven does for build-by-convention, but is completely customizeable and so it doesn't force you to convert all of your projects to the Maven convention.  It has the same great dependency management (it can even use Maven's repositories).  I've converted two different companies from Ant to Gradle and I couldn't be happier with it both in terms of ease-of-use and powerful flexibility

Comment: That actually does sound awesome.  I converted one app to Maven and it was kind of a pain to get building correctly because I had to move so much stuff around to match the Maven convention. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Quite welcome, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no longer working on this project, so am closing this question. The solution we went with was to add security exceptions for the URL that the applet was hosted from using a group policy.